# Django ORM - sort by name and score

Tags: django, django-orm

I have these two models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Score(models.Model):
    score = models.BigIntegerField()
    game = ForeignKey(Game, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...
```

And I would like to order all the scores by:

1. Game name
2. Score within the game

So, the results I want is:

**Game A**

- 100.000
- 90.000
- 80.000

**Game B**

- 50.000
- 40.000
- 30.000

**Game C**

- 200.000
- 190.000
- 180.000

I hope you get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: Are the models related by a ForeignKey? Add the full models

Comment: @gdef_ Sorry, I forgot the ForeignKey. I've added the foreign key. There's a lot of irrelevant of properties that I haven't posted. I can't see how they can be useful now.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `order_by` in the ORM, combined with the builtin template tag `regroup` will do exactly what you're looking for. The [example in the Django docs for `regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) is almost exactly what you're trying to do.

I'm assuming your `Score` model has a `ForeignKey` to the `Group` model.

In your view, you would do something like this:

```
# views.py

class ScoreListView(ListView):
    model = Score

    queryset = Score.objects.select_related('game') \
                            .order_by('game__name', '-score')
```

```
# score_list.html

<!-- other content -->

{% regroup scores by game as game_list %}

{% for game, game_scores in game_list %}
<h2>{{ game }}</h2>
<ul>
  {% for score in game_scores %}
    <li>{{ score.score }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you should add `select_related` for completeness.. so it is done correctly from the beginning.

Comment: @GregKaleka Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!